# ASP.net Web API 2 AJAX sending JSON and return JSON

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json, ajax, asp.net-web-api2

net Web API 2. I am wanting to send a JSON string to one of my POST functions and return JSON back to it.

My AJAX:

```
$("#btnPost").click(function (event) {
 var sqlQ = "SELECT TOP 50 LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(OID, ' ', ''))) FROM vwPS_DAT WHERE OID != ''";

   $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       crossDomain: true,
       dataType: 'json',
       async: true,
       cache: false,
       contentType: "application/json",
       url: "api/FEB/testJSON/",
       data: JSON.stringify({ qString: [sqlQ] }),
       success: function (result) {
              var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
              console.log(obj);
       },
       error: function (xhr, status, error) {
              var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
              $("#txtResult").val(err.Message)
       }
   });
}
```

The Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public string testJSON([FromBody]List<string> qString)
{
    System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer ser = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();

    Dictionary<string, string> outPut = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    var strReturn = ser.Serialize(qString);
    var strReturn2 = ser.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, string>>(strReturn);

    if (strReturn2["qString"] != "")
    {
        outPut.Add("query", "correct");

        return ser.Serialize(outPut);
    }
    else
    {
        outPut.Add("query", "incorrect");

        return ser.Serialize(outPut);
    }
}
```

APP_Start:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");

        config.EnableCors(cors);
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"));
        config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.MediaTypeMappings.Add(new RequestHeaderMapping("Accept", "text/html", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase, true, "application/json"));

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "ActionApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
       );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

The HTML Page:

```
<body>
<div style="text-align:center">
    <h2>AJAX JQuery JSON test</h2>
    Please enter Value1 :   <input type="number" id="txtValue1" min="1" max="100"><br><br>
    Please enter Value2 :   <input type="number" id="txtValue2" min="1" max="100"><br /><br>
    Result from Math API Service : <input type="text" id="txtResult" disabled /><br /><br>
    <input type="button" value="POST" id="btnPost">
</div>
```

The error I get when pushing the POST button is:

> POST http://localhost:53157/Web/api/FEB/testJSON/ 404 (Not Found)
>
> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

So what all would I be missing since it doesn't even seem to be finding the function as well?

Comment: JSON.stringify({ qString: [sqlQ] }) this might be problem, i think

Comment: If it is not your JSON thing then try it using `url: "/api/FEB/testJSON/"` instead of `url: "api/FEB/testJSON/"` with a `"/"` prefixed before `api`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add DTO class and use:

```
 public class Dto
    {
        public List<string> qString { get; set; } 
    }
```

And Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public Dictionary<string, string> testJSON(Dto dto)
{
    var outPut = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    foreach (string query in dto.qString)
    {
        string status = query != string.Empty ? "correct" : "incorrect";

        outPut.Add(query, status);
    }

    return outPut;
}
```

And now you can change this code:

```
 data: JSON.stringify({ qString: [sqlQ] }),
       success: function (result) {
              var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
              console.log(obj);
       },
```

to:

```
 data: JSON.stringify({ qString: [sqlQ] }),
       success: function (result) {
              console.log(result);
       },
```

Comment: if i only did **sqlQ** then that would not be JSON (as in, it wouldn't have the **qString** with it for me to look for).

Comment: I'm getting an error of **{"Type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]' is not supported for deserialization of an array."}**

Comment: On the **string>>(strReturn)** which has a value of **["SELECT TOP 50 LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(OID, \u0027 \u0027, \u0027\u0027))) FROM vwPS_DAT WHERE OID != \u0027\u0027"]**

Comment: Please see now, little changed your code, but the effect is the same in my opinion

Comment: If you are using WebAPI that you do not have to string serialization and client-side parse again